# Obtaining kafka topics produced and consumed by a microservice

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Is there any code/command I can use in Kafka to see all the topics produced and consumed by a microservice?

Alternatively is there any command I can execute on a Spring Boot kafka microservice to obtain the input and output topics and consumer group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing related to kafka itself, but mainly you are looking for the open/distributed tracing concept.

There are many open source tools support open tracing, like [Jeager](https://www.jaegertracing.io/) and [zipkin](https://zipkin.io/)

here is an [example provided by strimzi](https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/10/08/strimzi-apache-kafka-and-tracing/)

Answer (score 0):

For consumers using consumer groups, you can already use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` to describe every group, and see every client and every topic used.

For producers, no, there is no way. Not without external client authentication request monitoring, or embedding other libraries such as distributed tracing.